# Separar una cantidad en millares, centenas, decenas y unidades

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente código que se pone debe controlar la interfaz de la imagen pero no funciona. Por favor algún consejo para que la cantidad que yo le envíe a una caja de texto y me muestre cuantos millares, centenas, decenas y unidades tiene.

¿Cómo puedo separar una cantidad en millares, centenas, decenas y unidades e ir contando cuántos tiene de cada unidad?

```js
function separarSifras(cantidad) {
  if (cantidad == "") {
    alert("Escribe una cantidad por favor");
  } else {
    if (!isNaN(cantidad.value)) {
      alert("Escibe solo numeros");
    } else {
      var cadeSifra = new String(cantidad.value);

      var longitudSifra = cantidad.length;

      var millares = "";
      var centenas = "";
      var decenas = "";
      var unidades = "";

      for (cont = 0; cont < longitud.length; cont++) {
        if (cadeSifra.charAt(cont) == '1') priNum++;


      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 align="center">Clasificador de monedas</h1>
<form>
  <table align="center" border=0>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Ingresa una cantidad:
        <input type="text" name="cantidad" maxlength="5" />
        <input type="button" value="Acomodar" onClick="separarSifras(this.form.cantidad)" />
      </th>
      <td align=center>
        <input type="button" value="Reiniciar" onclick="window.location.reload()" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
<br>
<table align="center" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Millares</td>
    <td>Centenas</td>
    <td>Decenas</td>
    <td>Unidades</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Me aparece el error

> ReferenceError: longitud is not defined

Comment: Hola Jesús, ¿cómo no te funciona? ¿Qué error ves en la consola?

Comment: ReferenceError: longitud is not defined

Comment: ¿Dónde defines `longitud`?¿Estás seguro que esa es la variable que debes usar?

Comment: ya realize un ejercicio paracido el cual me permite contar el numero de vocales que contiene una oracion, pero me gustia hacer otro que me permita saber cuantas unidades, decenas, centenas y millares tiene x cantidad

Comment: espero por favor me puedan orientar

Comment: Hay varios problemas en el código: entre ellos que no estás definiendo/asignando variables antes de usarlas, ¿qué se supone que es `longitud`?¿y `priNum`? ¿De dónde salen y qué valor deberían tener?

Comment: si tiene mucha razon

Answer (score 2):

Una forma sencilla de descomponer el número es crear un array de caracteres a partir del valor y extraerlos uno a uno.

```js
function separarSifras(cantidad) {
  
  if (cantidad.value == "") {
    alert("Escribe una cantidad por favor");
    return;
  }

  // Obtener valor numérico
  var valor = parseInt(cantidad.value);

  if (isNaN(valor)) {
    alert("Escibe solo numeros");
  } else {
    // Crear array de caracteres a partir del número
    var cadeSifra = valor.toString().split("");

    document.getElementById('unidades').innerText = 
      cadeSifra.length ? cadeSifra.pop() : '';
    document.getElementById('decenas').innerText = 
      cadeSifra.length ? cadeSifra.pop() : '';
    document.getElementById('centenas').innerText = 
      cadeSifra.length ? cadeSifra.pop() : '';
    // Convertimos el resto del array a cadena
    document.getElementById('millares').innerText = 
      cadeSifra.length ? cadeSifra.join('') : '';
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 align="center">Clasificador de monedas</h1>
<form>
  <table align="center" border=0>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Ingresa una cantidad:
        <input type="text" name="cantidad" maxlength="5" />
        <input type="button" value="Acomodar" onClick="separarSifras(this.form.cantidad)" />
      </th>
      <td align=center>
        <input type="button" value="Reiniciar" onclick="window.location.reload()" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
<br>
<table align="center" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Millares</td>
    <td>Centenas</td>
    <td>Decenas</td>
    <td>Unidades</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span id="millares"></span></td>
    <td><span id="centenas"></span></td>
    <td><span id="decenas"></span></td>
    <td><span id="unidades"></span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Me aparece el error
>
> > ReferenceError: longitud is not defined

El error señalado se muestra cuando el valor de entrada no es un número cuando debería ser lo contrario. Cambia

```
if (!isNaN(cantidad.value)) {
```

por

```
if (isNaN(cantidad.value)) {
```

Además el código cuenta con otros errores no relacionados con el título de la pregunta, algunos ya mencionados en comentarios como el uso de variables no definidas, tales como `longitud` y `primNum` y otros como la publicación del resultado.